# eval in Firefox Addon

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, eval

I have written a Firefox addon which uses "eval". Assuming there is no way to avoid using eval, what is the best way to make this safe within the addon?

The editor who evaluated my addon was kind enough to specify that *Please evaluate the script in a sandbox that can not access any browser functions*, but I have to say I have no idea how to do this.

The addon includes code from [Dean Edward's Unpacker](http://dean.edwards.name/unpacker/) and from [Codemirror](https://codemirror.net/) and this is where the eval is used.

Would somebody be able to help?

Comment: Add the relevant code to your question. You can probably avoid using `eval`.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I added a clarification

Comment: `eval` is not accepted. You have to make a super strong case there is no other way around it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Appendix_C:_Avoid_using_eval_in_Add-ons?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=XUL_School%2FAppendix_C%3A_Avoid_using_eval_in_Add-ons - if the `eval` is used by popular 3rd party lib, that's a case to appeal for.

Comment: Thanks @Noitidart, interesting tip

Answer (score 0):

> Please evaluate the script in a sandbox that can not access any browser functions, but I have to say I have no idea how to do this

Use [Cu.Sandbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components.utils.Sandbox) and [Cu.evalInSandbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components.utils.evalInSandbox). With those you can run any javascript in isolation and then use the [structured clones](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm) of objects to access results in a safe manner.

To load scripts from files into the sandbox you can also use the [subscript loader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/mozIJSSubScriptLoader)

Comment: Thanks @the8472. Is there any chance you could show me how to implement this?

Comment: I could, yes. But considering that I've linked to multiple, quite extensive pages of documentation while you have not shown any effort of trying to work with that I'm not inclined to provide a solution on a silver platter.